# Flutter Syncfusion SfCircularChart custom double value

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I want to have a custom `maximumValue` per ChartData so that each chart has its own value.

the ChartData looks like this (adding `totalCount` setter)

```
class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y, [this.totalCount]);
  final String x;
  final double y;
  final double? totalCount;
}
```

then its data instantiator

```
 final chartData = [
      ChartData('ONE', 3, 20),
      ChartData('TWO', 10, 100),
    ];
```

then in the implementation when I want to add the `totalCount` from the `ChartData` like this:

```
SizedBox(
   height: 300.0,
   child: SfCircularChart(series: <CircularSeries>[
   // Renders radial bar chart
   RadialBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
      dataSource: chartData,
      xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
      yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y,
      maximumValue: (ChartData data, _) => data.totalCount,)
  ])),
```

I get the message that:

```
The argument type 'double? Function(ChartData, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double?'
```

so how do I get the double value `totalCount` to populate the `maximumValue` with a `double` value and not a `Function(ChartData, dynamic)`

I've looked around but can't find an answer. Is this possible?

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: yes thanks, the licensing begins at $1Mil income, which is fine.

Comment: Read that more carefully.  Starts at 1MM, *or* 5 collaborators.  You'll likely hit that 5 count pretty darn quick.  And then also remember, any downstream has to also qualify similarly.

Comment: very good sir, thank you think i'll use pie_chart instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seeing as I'd need some kind of `maximumValueMapper` , this is not available in a closed source package such as syncfusion.

closing

Answer (score -1):

Based on the provided code snippet, we understand that you are attempting to set the maximum value for each segment of the [RadialBarSeries](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/RadialBarSeries-class.html) and the mentioned typecast error occurs because the data type of the **double? Function(ChartData, dynamic)** does not match the data type of the [maximumValue](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/RadialBarSeries/maximumValue.html) property, which is of type **double**.

It is important to note that the [maximumValue](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/RadialBarSeries/maximumValue.html) property is used to set the maximum value for the entire series, and there is no option to set the maximum value for each individual segment. To avoid the mentioned typecast error, you can modify the sample code as shown below.

```
class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  late List<ChartData> chartData;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    chartData = [
      ChartData('ONE', 3, 20),
      ChartData('TWO', 20, 100),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          height: 300.0,
          child: SfCircularChart(
            series: <CircularSeries>[
              // Renders radial bar chart
              RadialBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
                dataSource: chartData,
                xValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) => sales.x,
                yValueMapper: (ChartData sales, _) => sales.y,
                maximumValue: 30,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also shared the User Guide documentation and sample browser links below regarding the [RadialBarSeries](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/RadialBarSeries-class.html) for your reference.

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/circular-charts/chart-types/radial-bar-chart.

SB: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/circular-charts/chart-types/radial-bar/default

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying, yes the issue is that I want `maximumValue` to be variable according to each ChartData segment